# When adding Facebook SDK " appeventslogger.activateapp(this)" is shown deprecated

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio-2.0

Using Facebook SDK 4.5. Tried using SDK 4.5 to 4.11. Problem still facing.

AS per this changelog : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4.x

Its changed to AppEventsLogger.activateApp(Application)

But I am facing trouble while implementing it.

[image: Screenshot]:

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Just replace `AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this)`  to

```
AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getApplication());
```

Comment: but then onPause deactivateApp() is deprecated

Comment: activateApp() is deprecated