# android - Facebook SDK not tracking installs

Tags: android, facebook

I'm running into an issue where facebook is tracking the unique users for android but not the app installs. All I'm doing in my activity is:

```
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getApplication());
```

In onCreate.

Should this not be tracked as an install even if I send an apk file?

Comment: you may find the solution here (read the answer and comments)[When adding Facebook SDK “ appeventslogger.activateapp(this)” is shown deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36857441/when-adding-facebook-sdk-appeventslogger-activateappthis-is-shown-deprecate)

Comment: Only thing I noticed different was that my call was before the super.onCreate. would that make a difference?